# How to get cancellation date of Auto-Renewable subscription?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I am developing iOS app which sells the "Auto-Renewable Subscriptions" via the IAP.
This app has to know the "date of the cancellation subscription" but I couldn't find the way so far.

Would you please tell me the way how to get cancellation date of Auto-Renewable subscription?

I have tried to confirm this point as below, but I couldn't find any clues.

- I suspect that the "expires_date" key, described in the ["Auto-Renewable Subscriptions"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW2) article, will store the date when users cancel the subscription. However, the article does not explain about it explicitly.
- I wrote a very simple program to test actual behavior of IAP, but it doesn't work well as I expected.
  (it always returned 21007 in the 'status' key when this sample validates the receipt in the 'sandbox mode' iTunes Connect, but it did not return the "expires_date" value at all).

Thank you for your help.

Hidehiko

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I did find some information [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html) though, but there doesn't seems to be any way to test this.

To summarize, there should be a **cancellation_date** field in the receipt. It should be in the same receipt you would find expires_date, both for iOS 6 & 7 transaction receipts! As you see, everything is based on "should".

Comment: Can we test ios in app purchase on production?Right now I dont find much useful documentation about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can find cancellation_date string in the [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH106-SW1), which indicates the subscribtion whether be canceled or not,and additional [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6)may helps too;